# how to work with relationship API of instagram in android?

Tags: android, api, instagram

I'm trying to work with the instagram api, and I'm not seeming to understand one of their request call from the relationship endpoint, so here goes,

```
GET /users/{user-id}/relationship and POST /users/{user-id}/relationship
```

this information comes from this page  "http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/"

how to work with this API for android application???with example for better understanding.

i tried "apigee"  from this page https://apigee.com/console/instagram but i got error like:

```
{ "meta": {
"error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError",
"code": 400,
"error_message": "please supply action=approve,ignore,follow,block,unblock,unfollow"}}
```

actually i don't know how to work with this POST and GET method which is describe above...

sorry for my bad English and my grammar mistake.
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with curl post method..following is a sample code for getting relation ship with the target user

```
$data = "action=follow";
$ch = curl_init('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user_id}/relationship?access_token={access_token}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)) );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```